# NaN values when new column is added to pandas DataFrame based on an existing column data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in pandas DataFrame which is based on another existing column. I am extracting characters `10:19` from column `Name` and adding it as a new column `expiry`  . But most of the datas in `expiry` are showing as `nan`. I am new to python and Pandas. How can I solve this ?

```
allowedSegment = [14]
index_symbol = "BANKNIFTY"

fno_url = 'http://public.fyers.in/sym_details/NSE_FO.csv'
fno_symbolList = pd.read_csv(fno_url, header=None)
fno_symbolList.columns = ['FyersToken', 'Name', 'Instrument', 'lot', 'tick', 'ISIN', 'TradingSession', 'Lastupdatedate',
                           'Expirydate', 'Symbol', 'Exchange', 'Segment', 'ScripCode', 'ScripName', 'Ignore_1',
                          'StrikePrice', 'CE_PE', 'Ignore_2']

fno_symbolList = fno_symbolList[fno_symbolList['Instrument'].isin(allowedSegment) & (fno_symbolList['ScripName'] == index_symbol)]

fno_symbolList['expiry'] = fno_symbolList['Name'][10:19]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with strings in columns and doing operations on it, try the following:

```
fno_symbolList['expiry'] = fno_symbolList['Name'].str[10:19]
```

The .str allows you to do string operations on columns.